# windows service with background worker Could not load file or assembly error

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, assembly-resolution, assemblybinding

I'm creating a windows service, which tests if a scheduled job may be executed and then it starts a background worker to  execute the job.

Within the main thread of the windows service, I create a data access layer(DAL) object, from an assembly which is located in the same directory as the windows service executable.
This works.

From within the background worker, I also try to create a new instance of the same object. It looks like this is successfull. A method in the DAL loads a SQL file from the assembly and is then executed against a give database.

Somewhere during this process I get the following error:

```
 System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\system32\DataConnector.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
    File name: 'file:///C:\Windows\system32\DataConnector.dll'
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at DataConnector.DatabaseConnector.UpdateDatabase()
```

I don't know why the background worker tries to look into the C:\windows\system32\ directory.

Comment: *A method in the DAL loads a SQL file from the assembly* - what does this mean? Is the SQL file compiled into the assembly?

Answer (score 3):

This will probably fix the issue:

```
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

Comment: -1 this is not caused by a coding issue - the problem is in assembly binding resolution.

Comment: @TomRedfern. I suspect this **is** a coding issue. The current directory for a service will be c:\windows\system32, hence I would suspect that the program (which is using Assembly.LoadFrom) is simply looking for the dll in the current directory. If that is the case, then this will probably fix the issue. The alternative would be to change the Assembly.LoadFrom to load the file from the correct directory.

Comment: After re-reading the question in light of @sgmoore's comment, I concede I was incorrect in my original assessment of coke head's answer. Apologies! - unfortunately I can't undo my down vote unless you update your answer...

Comment: @TomRedfern - No prob. mate., when I saw the down-vote, I presumed I must have misread Mischa's question. In any case I updated my answer.